# Reverse process of XOR

Tags: c#, reverse, xor

I was thinking, when two byte array is **XOR**'ed, is there any way to reverse the process? As I am curious to find the answer I found this code in the google which is the **XOR** code and this is the pseudocode of step1 (**XOR** code)

[image]

The **XOR** code:

```
public static byte[] XOR(byte[] first, byte[] second)
    {
        if (first.Length == second.Length)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[first.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = (byte)(first[i] ^ second[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

The code works fine. Now down below is the pseudocode of step2 (reverse of **XOR** code) 
[image]

I am very confused how to do this step2. How can I reverse the process to get back the original byte arrays? As the only input I have is the `result`. Is this ever possible? Is there any way to do this? If the answer is yes then how?

Comment: You cannot reverse "result" without knowing "first" or "second". "first XOR result = second", or "second XOR result = first".

Comment: What the picture seems to show is that 128bits of information were somehow stored in 64bits, obviously that's not going to happen

Comment: @harold, the arrow is the missing(unknown) process to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you mentioned in your comment:

"I have to marge two byte arrays into one (all having same bits) and reverse the process to get back the original two arrays."

This process can not be carried out by using bitwise operations. XOR, however, can be reversed if and only if you define a decryption key which in case of your question, it is not applicable.

The best practice to merge two sets of numbers and still be able to get back the original data can be done by creating a 2 linear and 2 unknown equation. Of course, in this process, what you store in your third array is not simply "one number" but a mathematical equation. This can be done using multi-dimensional arrays to keep the values of X, Y, etc for each equation.

This is the simplest approach for abstracting two collections of data.

Comment: OMG! what an idea! The dream I'm chasing, the project I'm thinking to give life, your idea might just work but it will surely bring huge change to the whole code of the project. But still many many thanks for this idea. :)

Answer (score 9):

Forget about the arrays - just solve it for one bit.

Starting with the truth table for XOR:

```
a | b | c
0   0 | 0
0   1 | 1
1   0 | 1
1   1 | 0
```

If C (the output) is zero, can you figure out A and B?  The answer is . . . no!

If you know that C is zero, then [A,B] was either [0,0] or [1,1].  The same thing happens if C is 1.  You know that [A,B] was either [0,1] or [1,0].

Now, if you happen to know A *and* C, then you can figure out B.  More generally, if you know two then you can figure out the 3rd.  If you only know one then you can narrow down the other values to two choices, but that's as far as you can get without additional information

Comment: Sigh. yes now it is clear to me that it is not possible as the way I thought it would be.

Answer (score 5):

XOR is a reversible process; if you XOR the result with the same 2-byte array you used in the first example, you will get back the original.  E.g. you have a two byte array `Array1`, and you `XOR` it with a two byte array `Array2` to get the result `Array3`. If you want to get back `Array1`, simply take `Array3 XOR Array2`. Hope this helps

Comment: If I knew the values of Array1 or Array2 then I should not have asked this question in the first place. As I told, I am given only Array3 as input to find the other two arrays. ---Anyway, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "XOR is a reversible process" is not generally a true statement (not talking about the asked question), XOR is by nature an Irreversible process, and that is because it is the result of merging an array of binary data. This means that there is no way to get all the original data which have been XORed. Many one way encryption systems like MD5 heavily rely on this bit-wise operation.

Comment: you could find *some* solutions, but there's no way to determine exactly what the two arrays were.

Comment: I suppose reversible was the wrong term to use, maybe symmetric?

Comment: @bkane521, are you saying symmetric keys or something like that?

Comment: @Giliweed not like that, I'm referring to the phenomenon where applying XOR with the same number twice leaves the original operand unaltered. I don't know if there's a term for that, but that's what I meant by reversible

Comment: okey, forget about XOR. My main problem is, I have to marge two byte arrays into one (all having same bits)  and reverse the process to get back the original two arrays. "XOR" is just a way/path/process that I thought it might work. but now I see it doesn't so, any other suggestion or way to do this? please I really want to do this.

Comment: you're asking to encode 128 bits into 64 bits, then decode it without loss? if you can figure that out, you'll have one nifty compression algorithm

Comment: @Giliweed certain combinations of 128 bits can be shrunk into 64 bits through compression and have the process be perfectly reversible (lossless compression) but it's certainly not possible for *every* combination of 128 bits.  You'll have to narrow down your problem space a bit.

Comment: @bkane521, yes you got my point. but I never heard of "nifty compression algorithms" before. Is it a special algorithm?

Comment: I meant you would have a great compression algorithm. I suggest you do a little investigation into compression algorithms and information theory if this type of stuff interests you; Pete Baughman is on point with his comment

Comment: @bkane521, yes it interests me a lot. As this reversal work really got into my head and I really want to find an answer(a correct process) to do this. Thanks for everything.